# Size of objects in Numpy Array: Sympy Points example

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sympy, numpy-ndarray

Here is attached some code in which it is attempted to instantiate a Numpy Array of Sympy Points given their coordinates.

```
from sympy.geometry import Point
import numpy as np

coordinates = np.array([2,0, 1,-1, 0,0, -2,3, -3,-2, 0.01,-0.01]).reshape(6,2) 

v1 = np.empty((coordinates.shape[0],),dtype=np.dtype(Point))
for index, value in enumerate(coordinates):
    v1[index] = Point(value)
print(v1)
# [Point2D(2, 0) Point2D(1, -1) Point2D(0, 0) Point2D(-2, 3) Point2D(-3, -2) Point2D(1/100, -1/100)]

v2 = np.empty((coordinates.shape[0],2),dtype=np.dtype(Point))
for index, value in enumerate(coordinates):
    v2[index] = Point(value)
print(v2)
# [[2 0]
# [1 -1]
# [0 0]
# [-2 3]
# [-3 -2]
# [1/100 -1/100]]

v3 = np.empty((coordinates.shape[0],1),dtype=np.dtype(Point))
for index, value in enumerate(coordinates):
    v3[index] = Point(value)
print(v3)
# ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 1
```

I would have expected that size 1 for the second index of the result should be correct way to do it (v3), because a Point should be 1 object but it gives an error.

v1 is what I would have expected to get doing it the v3 way. Why does it have to be done the v1 way? Why is v1 wrong? Why is v2 not a vector of Sympy Points?